# click on a link from a list of drop down links in uft

Tags: vbscript

```
<span class="allMnuHdr">Marketing</span>

<a href="index.php?module=Campaigns&action=index&parenttab=Marketing" class="allMnu">Campaigns</a>

<a href="index.php?module=Accounts&action=index&parenttab=Marketing" class="allMnu">Accounts</a>

<a href="index.php?module=Contacts&action=index&parenttab=Marketing" class="allMnu">Contacts</a>

<a href="index.php?module=Webmails&action=index&parenttab=Marketing" class="allMnu">Webmail</a>
```

I am trying to click a link with in a link. In this case, When I hover the mouse on the link, I'll see a list of links & I want to click on one of those.I've tried many a few things but no luck.

From the above HTML code, you can see "Marketing" is a parent link & it has some more links within. I want to click on "Accounts" after hovering the mouse on "Marketing". I've tried `getRoproperty("allitems")` method & that doesn't return any thing. While I record the script, I can see the reference to child link as below

```
Browser("admin - My Home Page -").Page("admin - My Home Page -").Link("Accounts").Click
```

I can't get this working using dynamic scripting. Can you please suggest an approach this can be worked in uft?

Comment: What does this have to do with vbscript?

Comment: It is supposed to be tagged to QTP & VB scripting community, apologies

Comment: In any case it's off topic for [su]. You could try http://sqa.stackexchange.com they have tags for boyh QTP and UFT